# Urldecode bug: after adding a simple product to shopping cart on search page and redirect to current page

Tags: magento, redirect, url-rewriting

Here is a scenario with Magento CE 1.7.0.2 If you are on catalog search page and list mode is on.

```
Url:  http://127.0.0.1/magento/catalogsearch/result/index/?mode=list&q=the
```

And redirect to current page after adding product to cart is Active in admin panel.

If you try to add simple product to cart, product added to cart successful but redirection URL is not decoded properly

```
All ‘&’ replaced by ‘&amp;’ and result in breaking search result...

Result URL: http://127.0.0.1/magento/catalogsearch/result/index/?mode=list&amp;q=the
```

I think this bug may be already attended but I don’t find any topic on it....

Kindly help in this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mufaddal for giving reference.
I got two easy ways to fix this:

### Way 1:-

You can just override/rewrite this helper app\code\core\Mage\Core\Helper\Abstract.php

With modification of below function :

```
public function escapeUrl($data) 
{ 
return htmlspecialchars($data); 
}
```

to

```
public function escapeUrl($data) 
{ 
return $data; 
}
```

---

### Way 2 (the best way) :

rewrite/override controller /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php

with below modified method :

```
protected function _getRefererUrl() 
{ 
$refererUrl = $this->getRequest()->getServer(’HTTP_REFERER’); 
if ($url = $this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_REFERER_URL)) { 
$refererUrl = $url; 
} 
if ($url = $this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_BASE64_URL)) { 
$refererUrl = Mage::helper(’core’)->urlDecode($url); 
} 
if ($url = $this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED)) { 
$refererUrl = Mage::helper(’core’)->urlDecode($url); 
}

$refererUrl = Mage::helper(’core’)->escapeUrl($refererUrl);

if (!$this->_isUrlInternal($refererUrl)) { 
$refererUrl = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl(); 
} 
return $refererUrl; 
}
```

To

```
protected function _getRefererUrl() 
{ 
$refererUrl = $this->getRequest()->getServer(’HTTP_REFERER’); 
if ($url = $this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_REFERER_URL)) { 
$refererUrl = $url; 
} 
if ($url = $this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_BASE64_URL)) { 
$refererUrl = Mage::helper(’core’)->urlDecode($url); 
} 
if ($url = $this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED)) { 
$refererUrl = Mage::helper(’core’)->urlDecode($url); 
}

//$refererUrl = Mage::helper(’core’)->escapeUrl($refererUrl);

if (!$this->_isUrlInternal($refererUrl)) { 
$refererUrl = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl(); 
} 
return $refererUrl; 
}
```

Comment: Why Way 2 is best over Way 1?

Comment: Because in way 2, we are stopping calling of function 'escapeUrl' (modified in way 1). So if we follow way 2 then we will save a extra calling of function which is not needed at all(as you can see in way 1 we have modified function to return parameter without processing).

Answer (score 0):

In this fle app\code\core\Mage\Core\Helper\Abstract.php  `public function escapeUrl($data)`
this function is responsible for weird url.

It use `htmlspecialchars` function of php whic replace `&` with `'&amp;'` see here http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

So what I do is comment this line `$this->getResponse()->setRedirect($returnUrl);` in my CartController `_goBack` method insrtead of I used my custom redirect method.

Comment: thanks man!

I think this is going to work but need to overwrite CartController...

Hope Magento will fix this issue in next version.

Comment: I am not able to fix this issue or not find any workaround so last I had to overwrite Cartcontroller